# Alerts not syncing to iPhone when creating google calendar event from iCal

Tags: iphone, sync, google-calendar, calendar.app

Before I explain what my problem is, I will outline my current configuration.

I am running 10.6, use iCal to modify events on my google calendar and this is done via CalDAV.

I also have an iPhone running 3.0.1, and modify events on my google calendar via `activesync`.

My problem is, that when I create an event in iCal, the alert does not appear when the event is synced to my iPhone, so it has been the case that alerts I set up on my mac, don't appear on my phone at all.

If I create an event on my iPhone, those alerts appear in iCal.

I'm not exactly sure why, but somewhere along the line, it appears as though the alert is removed.

Is there a setting somewhere I am missing that is causing synchronisation to act this way?

Comment: Does the alert appear correctly in google calendar after it has been synced from iCal? Do events created directly in google calendar sync properly? It would be useful to determine if its the iCal to google calendar step, or the google calendar to iPhone step that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what the problem was.

Alerts created in google calendar directly synchronise correctly to both iCal and iPhone. I have discovered that the issue is when creating an event in iCal, and setting the alert to be 'Message with Sound'. If the option for 'Message' is selected, then he alerts syncronise correctly in google calendar, iPhone and iCal.

Comment: I have the same problem, but there is only "Message with sound", "Email", and "Open file" available as types of alerts :(